# How to find out if $101^{100} -1$ is divisible with $100,1000,10000$ or $100000$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have figured out this but me solution is pretty long. Can anyone tell an easier method?

$101^{100}$ can be written as $(((((101)^2)^2)^5)^5)$

Now, $101^2$ = $10,201$

if we will multiply $101$ by $101$ itself the starting(unit place) would be $1$ and the tens place will be $0$ because first the number would be written the same as we will first multiply by $1$ and below it we will write zeros as we'll have to multiply by 0(the next digit), therefore $01$ will prevail.Is just standard log multiplication method.

Now any number to power will have the unit place digit same as the original number, therefore 01 will also prevail after the powers of $5$.

therefore $101^{100}$ will be equal to ...blah,blah,01
Now subtracting $1$ will result in havin $101^{100}$ divisible by 100.
Am I right?

Comment: Regardless of whether you're right or wrong, don't use "blah,blah" in your question if you're expecting it to be taken seriously.

Answer (score 8):

If you know the binomial theorem, the following hint will help:
$$(100+1)^{100}-1 = 100^{100}+\binom{100}{1}100^{99}+\dots+\binom{100}{99}100+(1-1)$$